# How to remove all html in TinyMCE Editor?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

In TinyMCE Editor,when you remove "p", just like the following code.

How to remove all ???

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.remove(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('p'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
```

[setContent reference](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent)

Comment: I have a hunch the OP means remove all HTML _around_ the content, not blast _all_ content. I could be very wrong.

Comment: @GrantThomas Could be. I'll leave the answer here until the OP clarifies.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Indeed, seems you were correct - while my tendency to read too much into things continues to blunt Occam's razor.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure only paragraphs get deleted use:

```
$(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).find('p').remove();
```

Due to the fact that `tinymce.activeEditor` gets set the first time when a user clicks in it it might be a better choice to use the explicit editor instance (which is available even before a user clicks into the editor). To get it use:

```
tinymce.get('your_editor_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple instances of tinymce textareas in the same page, you might use:

```
tinyMCE.get('your-textarea-id').setContent('');
```